# Flutter gradle error Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2]

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

All use to work fine but now suddenly when I try to build apk with flutter its giving me this error:

```
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I have         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2' in dependency

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please share a few more details about your issue? Are you running the build command from the terminal or from your IDE?

Comment: thanks for the welcome. I am not sure what I did but the issue is solved. May be android studio restart did the magic